# D3JS blink link

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hyperlink, tree, nodes

I am using d3js collapsible tree.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

How to make link blink(flash)? Can nodes also  be made to show/hide at regular interval? I hope it can be done without using setInterval.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the links "blink" you'll want to use a transition. Honestly there's nothing wrong with `setInterval`, in fact I'd probably use it for ease.

Firstly you want the animation. It'd difficult to know what you mean by "blink" so I'm going to assume gets brighter for now - but you can change this up however you wish.

```
d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(".link")
  .transition()
  .duration(500) // miliseconds
  .style("stroke", "white");
```

This will gradually change the style to `white` over a period of 500ms. Now you need to revert the color back to the original. You can do this using the `end` event on the transition object.

```
.on("end", function() {
   d3.select(this).style("stroke", "#CCC");
});
```

Note that in the above `this` is the `HTMLElement` that the transition was running on. You can do this with a lambda (arrow function) if need be but you need to do `(d, i, elements) => d3.select(elements[i]);`

Now you've got you're transition, which resets. But you want to call it regularly. Honestly, the easiest way to do this is using setInterval... So your final code would look like:

```
// Create the regular interval
setInterval(() => {
    d3.select("svg")
      .selectAll(".link")
      .transition()
      .duration(500) // miliseconds
      .style("stroke", "white")
      .on("end", function() {
          d3.select(this).style("stroke", "#CCC");
      });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, how to select particular link, say with id =1?

Comment: Just use the selector `"#link1"` if that's the I'd of your link. I'D attributes have to start with a letter.

Comment: .on was giving error, so I used .each and it worked. Only problem is all nodes are shifted from their position, so links and node appear floating separately

Comment: @yogi the position of the nodes shouldn't be related to this answer - this should be purely styling. Also `.on` should work fine - here's a link to it in the docs https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on